# KeyError on the 2nd loop on pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

so on the first run in the loop everything works fine but on the second loop, it causes a KeyError on the column values on my df. I don't understand why this is happening since in every loop I'm triggering a set of functions.

Part of the code that creates the error

```
def market_data (crypto, ts_float):

  #request to kraken for pricing data

  r = requests.get('https://futures.kraken.com/api/charts/v1/trade/' + crypto + '/15m?from=' + ts_float)


  #set JSON response to data
  data = r.json()

  #normalize data into dataframe
  df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['candles'])

  #convert unix time back into readable time
  df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='ms')

  #set time as index
  df = df.set_index('time')

  #convert into integer for calculations
  df['open'] = df['open'].astype(float).astype(int)
  df['high'] = df['high'].astype(float).astype(int)
  df['low'] = df['low'].astype(float).astype(int)
  df['close'] = df['close'].astype(float).astype(int)
  df['volume'] = df['volume'].astype(float).astype(int)

  return df

crypto_pairs = [
                {"crypto": "pf_ethusd", "size": 0.05},
                {"crypto": "pf_btcusd", "size": 0.0003},
                {"crypto": "pf_avaxusd", "size":3},
                {"crypto": "pf_dotusd", "size":10},
                {"crypto": "pf_ltcusd", "size":1.5}
                ]

 # getting the timstamp to get the data from
ts = (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 48)).timestamp()
ts_float = str(int(ts))

for cryptos in enumerate(crypto_pairs):
  data = market_data(cryptos[1]['crypto'], ts_float)

KeyError: time
```

I have a set of functions in my enumerate loop and the market_data which is the first one generates the mentioned error on the 2nd loop. The errors are always happening when changing the column names such as "time" and "open".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have skills in 'request', but this worked for me. Try the following. In the 'deep market_data' function, after receiving the dataframe, set a check, if len(df)<=0, then exit.

Where the dataframe turns out to be empty, the request returns 200, that is, everything is fine. Printed out 'crypto'. An empty dataframe is obtained on 'pf_btcusd'. I tried to swap it and again an empty dataframe turns out to be 'pf_btcusd'. Something is wrong with this symbol.

```
def market_data (crypto, ts_float):

  #request to kraken for pricing data

  r = requests.get('https://futures.kraken.com/api/charts/v1/trade/' + crypto + '/15m?from=' + ts_float)
  #print(r.status_code)


  #set JSON response to data
  data = r.json()

  #normalize data into dataframe
  df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['candles'])
  if len(df) <=0:
      print(r.status_code)
      print(crypto)
      return
```

Comment: hi thanks for it and sorry for only checking now! I figured it out be pf_btcusd just like you mentioned, the len check is a good idea